# Extract form parameter in Extract Variables policy

Tags: apigee

I am trying to extract a form param in an Extract Variables policy without success. `request.formparam.grant_type` successfully extracts the form parameter value but when I do the following it doesn't work. I don't understand what I am doing wrong I have made the request with the header `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as specified in the documentation but nothing seems to work. I must be doing something really silly but cannot spot what.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Extract-Variables-1">
    <FormParam name="grant_type"/>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Source clearPayload="false">request</Source>
    <VariablePrefix>apigee</VariablePrefix>
</ExtractVariables>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the variable in which to save the form parameter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Extract-Variables-1">
    <FormParam name="grant_type">
        <Pattern>{grantType}</Pattern>
    </FormParam>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Source clearPayload="false">request</Source>
    <VariablePrefix>apigee</VariablePrefix>
</ExtractVariables>
```

Since you have set your `VariablePrefix` to "apigee", the form parameter `grant_type` will be saved in the variable `apigee.grantType`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I tried the suggestion and unfortunately didn't work for me, in the end I raised a support request and the following works

`FormParam name="grant_type"><Pattern>{grant_type}</Pattern></FormParam>`

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for trying to respond from memory :) . I've corrected my answer in case someone else comes looking. Glad Support was able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Apigee Support helped me out and the following works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Extract-Variables-1">
    <FormParam name="grant_type"><Pattern>{grantType}</Pattern></FormParam>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Source clearPayload="false">request</Source>
    <VariablePrefix>apigee</VariablePrefix>
</ExtractVariables>
```